# GitHub actions: going through with pages-build-deployment

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages

I have a GitHub page being deployed on my main repo (x.github.io). This website is being update through GitHub actions from others repo which pushes files to this main repo. The action `pages-build-deployment` is triggered each time there's a push to the main repo. However, some pushes take place close to one another, so the `pages-build-deployment` gets canceled and reruns in order to deploy the latest version of the website.

How can I stop this behavior so that it doesn't get canceled and instead finishes the current deployment?

[image]

Comment: @GuiFalourd maybe you have an idea how to deal with this? :-)

Comment: Hi @mat! Thank you for tagging me (I just didn't receive any notification, which can explain my delay to answer). Is the repository public so I can reproduce the behavior and make some tests on a fork? Moreover, did you try using some actions that prevent duplicate workflow-runs? Example of such action, skip-duplicate: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/skip-duplicate-actions

Comment: @mat Do you want it to finish newer actions after it finished the oldest one?

Answer (score 1):

You should try defining concurrency at your workflow.

ex.:

```
concurrency: 
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}
  cancel-in-progress: false
```

More info: [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#concurrency) and [here](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-04-19-github-actions-limit-workflow-run-or-job-concurrency/)

Comment: It seems this "pages-build-deployment" action comes automatically after you activate github pages when there's a push, so no workflow file to change.

Comment: Any news on where these workflows should be edited, @Benur21?

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem. By default when you configure Github Pages it uses the *pages-build-deployment* action which is not modifiable. In my particular case I only want the action to be executed when there is a change in the folder that hosts the documentation of my project, for which the only solution is to use a [custom workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#publishing-with-a-custom-github-actions-workflow), as indicated in the documentation.

[Github Pages Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUWxo.png)

As you can see in the image, in your repository settings, in the Pages section, under Build and deployment you can select the source, which is by default: *Deploy from a branch* and will use the classic *pages-build-deployment* workflow. The alternative option is to use Github Actions, so you can configure the process to your preference.